# Embed map from Google Maps not delivering address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, embed

I have embed a map from GoogleMaps (new version) into my website. Everything is working fine, I've got the right address in the top left corner and the right view in my map. But if you click the link "view in Google maps" (I don't know how it is called in English - in German it is "In Google Maps ansehen"), then it opens the right map in GoogleMaps but there is no address in the top left corner.

Is there a way to fix this?

I chose a random address for this example (Behrenstraße 12, Berlin):

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2427.994226856034!2d13.386257899999997!3d52.51544355!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x47a851c4da0361af%3A0x9abbb70ae384577d!2sBehrenstra%C3%9Fe+12!5e0!3m2!1sde!2sde!4v1392728725174" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
```

Here is the map on JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3aNv3/
You can try and click the link "view in Google maps". You can see the Behrenstraße in Berlin but the address in the top left corner is missing.

Comment: It is showing on mine. Could it perhaps be because I'm logged into my Google account in the browser (chrome). Could you try and replicate that and see if the issue persists?

Comment: No, logging me into my Google account didn't help. Maybe it is because the address is not registered yet in Google Maps, because when I replace my address with a famous building it works fine.

Comment: Possibly, but that wouldn't explain why it worked on mine with the fiddle provided first time... Testing with latest chrome or is this a specific browser issue?

Comment: I've tested it in latest Chrome, Firefox and Safari on Mac. I see the address in the top left corner on JSFiddle. Clicking on "view in Google Maps" it is the right Map but no address. 
This is how it looks like on JSFiddle:
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/z3vb6tpya1325a8/googlemaps-fiddle.png)
[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0h3kldle6w49kkk/googlemaps.png)

Comment: Sorry. And the second link is how it looks like on Google Maps